# Return Closest Known Coordinate When Entering a New Coordinate - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, coordinates

I have a sheet of known coordinates laid out as Col A - Point Number, Col B - X Value, Col C - Y Value, Col D - Z Value; see below image (a lot more rows in reality).

[image: First 10ff rows and example entered coordinate]

I am looking for a way of entering a new coordinate and returning the point number of the closest coordinate. Have tried several ways myself but can't seem to get anything to work - if anyone can offer any assistance it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick in a single cell:

```
=LET(  Distance,  ( ($G$2-B2:B11)^2 + ($H$2-C2:C11)^2 + ($I$2-D2:D11)^2 )^0.5,

       XLOOKUP( MIN( Distance ), Distance, A2:A11  )
       )
```

It just calculates the distances for all existing points, then finds the `MIN` of them. Once found, it uses it in an `XLOOKUP` to find the name of said closest point.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution with additional column:

```
E2=($G$2-$B2)^2+($H$2-$C2)^2+($I$2-$D2)^2
```

Drag down till the last row with data.

```
F2=INDIRECT("$A$"&(MATCH(MIN($E:$E),$E:$E,0)),1)
```

---

In additional column we calculate the square distance. In destination cell we search the least value in the column and return point name from according row.

If more than one row have the same distance then the most upper of them will be used.

Pay attention - all cells in `E` column except oned in the data table must be empty!